# Possiblity to transform an Object to Bone

Tags: rigging, objects, armature, bones, transforms

I have a medical scan of a spine, I seperated all 24 vertebrae from each other in Meshlab and I wanted to use those as bones/armature for a Rig. But those are Objects and not Bones, can i use these 24 vertebrae as bones somehow?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bones are meant to deform mesh, so I would think you would just have the spine scan be deformed by the actual armature in a slightly unrealistic way, rather than be super scientifically accurate and make a multidozen bone spinal cord. However, you might go with a mix and use bendy bones, which deform things in even unified segments rather than blending with vertex groups.

If you REALLY want a bone to look like a spinal segment, you can. It’s called “bone shapes,” though I’m not sure how it’s done. However, bone shapes will not appear in the final render any more than bones do.

Comment: First of all thank your for your time ZargulTheWizard,
I'm aware of the behaviour of a bone, even as a newbie :,) thank you for bringing it up though. However, my goal is to add scientific accurate functions of a spine to a basis Rig like Rigify in terms of range of motion based on the MRI scan and constraint limitation between the bones (vertebrae). That said it's not about shape of every single Vertebrae its about the curvature of the spine based on the scan.

Comment: @user125304 I see. Okay, sorry about that.